# dotenv environment variables problem with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, dotenv

My project structure look like this:

```
|-project
   |-src
     |-index.ts
   |-.env
```

in index.ts I'm trying to load environment variables:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

I've also tried with

```
dotenv.config({
    path: __dirname+"/../.env"
});
```

file .env itself is surely ok,
where is the mistake? Thank for help

command that I'm running is `ts-node ./src/index.ts`

edit: I'm accesing values using expression like `process.env.DB_CONNECT`

.env file

```
DB_CONNECT=someValue
TOKEN_KEY=someValue
```

Comment: Maybe try `require('dotenv').config();`

Comment: doesn't work,  either with or without config object and any way to describe path in this object

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your config file and how you are accessing the values ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: resolve(__dirname, "../.env") });
```

Answer (score -1):

nevermind, it was my bad implementation of default values in functions.
closing